# Child added by jQuery with float is not created properly in Webkit

Tags: jquery, css, class, css-float, append

I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or it's unable to do it but I can't get what I expect in Chrome/Safari, but Firefox, Opera and IE do it well.
Here is the point.

I have a form with some kind of fields, divided on div's and one button to add the last 2 elements again to the form.
Forget it's a form and its possible problems at the time of processing via PHP the info if you like, let's focus on the markup problem I'm experiencing.

that's the original HTML code:

```
<div id="insert_group_work" class="insert_group form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Datos del obra</label>
    <input type="text" id="obra_nombre" class="form-control insert_group6" name="obra_nombre-1" placeholder="Nombre de la obra"/>
    <select id="select_composiciones" name="select_composiciones-1" class="form-control insert_group6">
        <option value="">Elige una tipo de composición</option>
        <option value="1">Viola solista</option>
        <option value="2">Música de cámara</option>
        <option value="3">Orquesta</option>
        <option value="4">Concierto</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button id="add_button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
```

here is the CSS class:

```
.insert_group6 { width:48.5%; margin-right:3%; float:left;}
```

and this is the jQuery script:

```
function addField() {
 var nuevaObra='<input type="text" id="obra_nombre'+numObra+'" class="form-control insert_group6" name="obra_nombre-'+numObra+'" placeholder="Nombre de la obra"/>';
 nuevaObra+='<select id="select_composiciones'+numObra+'" name="select_composiciones-'+numObra+'" class="form-control insert_group6">';
 nuevaObra+='<option value="">Elige una tipo de composición</option>';
 nuevaObra+='<option value="1">Viola solista</option>';
 nuevaObra+='<option value="2">Música de cámara</option>';
 nuevaObra+='<option value="3">Orquesta</option>'
 nuevaObra+='<option value="4">Concierto</option></select>';
 numObra++;
 $('#insert_group_work').append(nuevaObra);
}
```

nuevaObra is the variable with HTML markup to append and is divided by lines just to work with it.

I doing the markup with Bootstrap just to learn to use it but I needed to modify some properties to adapt to my personal case. That's why I use .insert_group6 class, to modify width, margin and float them to have 2 fields per line.

On my testing, the problem cames from floating the first element added via jQuery.

Normal use) Both elements added via jQuery has float:left property on my CSS class.
   Result- New elements added are no visible but are added to the DOM with wrong measures and position, over the top of parent div with negative measures.

Test 1) add manually two fields repeating the code.
   Result- everything seems ok, all the elements are created properly.

Test 2) add via jQuery the elements but the first has a class with no float.
   Result- fields are painted, but obiously the first doesn't float so there are in a column.

Test 3) Both elements added with float:left property activated and via Google developers uncheck and check again the property.
   Result- At first the elements are not well defined, when float_left is unchecked they appear in a colum, when I check again they are well positioned as the HTML created.

Test 4) Add elements without float and add the property after via Google Developer.
   Result- They are positioned in a column, but when I add the property manually in GD they get relocated to the right place.

I hope you can understand the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID, change your code to use classes intead.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explained I have a variable to count iterations.
Even solving that problem of HTML validation, the problem persist don't painting the boxes on the html markup.
I tried with a two classes common div with no id and it's 0x0 px too

Comment: What classes are you adding? Which element are you adding them to?

Comment: I'm appending a whole html markup with two classes. The elements are the input and select and they have in the code -> class="form-control insert_group6" <-

Comment: Can you show us the CSS bits?

Comment: You can probably get more information from Chrome Developer Tools. In Firebug (the Firefox equivalent of Developer Tools), you can see this by opening the "HTML" tab and selecting the element from the tree (or by selecting it from the browser window itself). In the panel on the right, if you then select the Style tab, it shows all the CSS properties, and tells you which clause in which CSS file they are using. With a bit of luck Chrome has something equivalent.

Comment: The first class is from Bootstrap, gives all the aspect and it works fine with the HTML fields. The second one is as simple as you can see->.insert_group6 { width:48.5%; margin-right:3%; float:left;}
I'm comparing html created and js created, they have the same classes and it seems the properties are active in the same way. HTML created elements has sizes but JS created not

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `<input>` and `<select>` parts of the HTML file and only have the javascript-generated elements? Or what happens if you have 2 copies in the HTML file?

Comment: If I get rid of the HTML generated, only apears the first time. Following times the elements created has negative measures.
If I put two copies on the HTML it seems right and working fine